# VBA to combine all sheets not working. One sheet does not merge

Tags: vba, excel

The following is supposed to take every sheet not named "Combined Reports" and merged into the sheet Combined Reports.

My workbook has 5 worksheets in the following order:

1. Combined Reports
2. New Leave Capture
3. Denial Capture
4. Open Leave Captuer
5. RTW Capture

My code captures sheets 3 through 5 but it is not capturing sheet 2.  Here is my code if anyone can help

```
Sub combine_all_Reports()

Dim J As Integer
Dim s As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name <> "Combined Reports" Then
        Application.GoTo Sheets(s.Name).[B9]
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined Reports"). _
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
        wksCombinedReports.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `On Error Resume Next` to `'On Error Resume Next` and try again.

Comment: Thank you. The second I took it off, I saw the error and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `Application.GoTo`, `Selection`, and `Select` and instead use fully qualified objects.

Your `For` loop code, could be much shorter (and faster), see the code below:

```
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name <> "Combined Reports" Then
        ' copy >> paste in 1 line
        s.Range("B9").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wksCombinedReports.Cells(wksCombinedReports.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

        wksCombinedReports.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

since you already know the sheets name in advance you could code like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub combine_all_Reports()
    Dim s As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("Combined Reports") ' reference "Combined Reports" sheet
        For Each s In Worksheets(Array("New Leave Capture", "Denial Capture", "Open Leave Captuer", "RTW Capture")) ' loop through specific sheets
            s.Range("B9").CurrentRegion.copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2) ' copy current sheet range B9 current region and paste to referenced sheet (i.e. "Combined Reports") 
        Next
        .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' autofit only once all copy&paste have been made
    End With
End Sub
```